# Is this bug a termite?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Noticed this bug on my kitchen floor, and am wondering whether it is a termite:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have a video of it crawling too, but don't see how to upload video here.

Edit:
Regarding scale: it is small, perhaps 3 mm (~1/8 inch).
Location is northern Arkansas, so is within termite territory.

Comment: Could you tell us your approximate location to aid in ID? Nice pictures BTW. but could you add some idea of scale.

Comment: Thank you @JiminyCricket. I have edited the question to include that additional info you suggested (~3mm and northern Arkansas).

Comment: As someone who is not entomologist, that would not even cross my mind as being a possible termite because the abdomen looks all wrong. It looks like a beetle to me. But as I said, not an entomologist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle) rather than a [termite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termite):
in comparison to a termite, most beetles have sclerotized forewings (so-called [elytra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elytron)) and from above, you can recognize its head, [pronotum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prothorax) and forewings.

Termites, however, have soft bodies and most often are wingless.
From above, you can additionally see their [meso-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesothorax) and [metanotum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathorax) and their abdominal [tergites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tergum) (latter are covered by the wings in most beetles).
Commonly, they are unpigmented and thus, pale.
[Winged termites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alate#In_entomology) have transparent wings that are longer than their bodies.

Beetles are extremely diverse with [almost 200 described beetle families with more than 300,000 species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle#Phylogeny), so it's super hard to tell even the family let alone the species from a photo.

[image: beetle vs termite]

---

Image source (in reading direction): [Sanjay Acharya CC-BY-SA-4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Isoptera.jpg) | [Teechippy CC-BY-SA-4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cluster_of_Dead_Formosan_Termites.jpg?fastcci_from=398956&c1=398956&d1=15&s=200&a=list) | [Dulneth Wijewardana CC-BY-SA-4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Heterotermes_alates.jpg?fastcci_from=398956&c1=398956&d1=15&s=200&a=list)